# Stopping laptop from fully discharging one of two batteries

Tags: windows, battery, lenovo-laptop

I have an 2017 Lenovo T470s. It contains two internal batteries. One of the batteries is a bit faulty - when it gets low on charge it sometimes 'disappears' from the system suddenly. This causes the laptop to instantly shut off without warning, and after a reboot the Lenovo health application warns me that the battery is missing. The battery 'reappears' when you charge it a few percent.

This happens consistently when the battery is < 10% remaining. Unfortunately it's also the battery that the laptop is discharging *first*:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way I can tell Windows to tell the laptop to stop discharging that battery below 10%? Or a way that I can use the other battery first? Somehow change the priority of the battery?

Third party programs are totally fine if I need to do that.

The only other real option I have is to remove the battery from the system, which is fine, but I do get a good 2 hours out of it which will be disappointing to lose.

Comment: If it is faulty and doing this then that is a sign of more problems likely to soon appear. Replacement would be a better option while you were simply removing it and neither battery is what I would call stupidly expensive: https://www.batterybuy.co.uk/battery-lenovo/thinkpad-t470s-lenovo-battery.htm

Comment: Sadly this is a US-spec laptop that I've taken back to Australia. Nobody will air-ship these batteries so my choices are very few and far between. I've checked FRU numbers on the batteries themselves and there is virtually no domestic stock, and the one that there is is over $200. The batteries appear fine, no swelling.

Comment: Maybe this helps, even if the model is slightly different: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/T480-Does-not-switch-to-secondary-battery-turns-off-unexpectedly-Win10/m-p/4398417?page=1#4398552

Answer (score 1):

Windows lets you set a "Critical Battery Level", which is the level below which an unexpected shutdown could happen. Normally, it is set to 2-4%, so you'll need to adjust this. Most probably, it is also the level at which the OS will switch to your second battery (can't test this on my system).

- Go to `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings`.
- Click on `Change advanced power settings`

Adjust your settings for "Critical battery level" and "Critical Battery Action", and if needed also for "Low battery level" and "Low battery Action" (see image below). Adjust your "Critical Battery Level" to about 11%, so your OS will know it's in danger of shutdown, and should switch automatically to the second battery once the first is below that level. (Make a test setting the level to 95%, so you can see if it behaves correctly.)

In any case, at the very least, once your "Critical Battery Level" is set to something above the "failure level" you have indicated, you can set "Critical Battery Action" to "hibernate", and you won't risk to loose your work with an unexpected shutdown.

You might have to repeat the steps for each of your power plans.

[image]

Comment: Problem is that these apply to the overall battery percentage. When one battery is discharged and one is full the overall percentage is still 50%. So I'd need to set these to roughly 55% which I doubt would bring me any benefit.